# Disable drag inertia / momentum on Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to disable drag inertia on Google Maps V3? Seems like it should be a MapOption, but I can't find any way to do this.

Comment: I guess this is a known problem with no solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with Maps API V3 at this time. Consider filing a feature request here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem today, with some custom Div's floating above the map needing to be re-positioned on Map Movement. My repositioning worked fine as long as the user came to a complete stop after dragging before letting the mouse go (so there would be no momentum), but if one just dragged quickly and released the div's would end up a bit off.

To fix this, I hooked into the drag event and the idle event:

```
var map = /* All the map config */
var stickyCenter = map.getCenter();
/* ... Code ... */
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function(){ stickyCenter = map.getCenter(); });
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() { map.setCenter(stickyCenter); });
```

What happens is that after you've dragged and the map has come to a stop (after the momentum is done) the map 'snaps' back into place.

If the snapping is too sudden, one could probably panTo or animate the movement in some way.  Hope that helps, it's not perfect, but it's a way to reverse the momentum from a drag event.

Comment: As of v3, you can hook into the `center_changed` event which will account for the time between the `dragend` and `idle` events. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: @DevinMcInnis Right you are. This was also discussed on the issue open on the google code here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3543&q=idle&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal


Specifically:

"This use case can be solved by adding an `idle` listener once a `dragend` event is triggered. The idle event fires once the map comes to rest.

To position the overlay, use `bounds_changed` or `center_changed` instead of `drag`"

Answer (score 4):

Use the undocumented option `disablePanMomentum` *e.g.:*

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
    disablePanMomentum: true,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: {
        lat: 40.674,
        lng: -73.945
    },
    zoom: 2,
    ...
```

Comment: Nice one. I'm curious about how did you found it.

Comment: @PedroAdameVergara Extensive reverse engineering or some basic regex skills.  Take your pick.

Comment: @Orwellophile could explain how you would use regexs to find this out? I would love to know, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's possible to at least counter-act the momentum. Somebody please correct me if I'm wrong! For the sake of simplicity, for instance, let's say your map container has a `width` of `100vw` and a `height` of `100vh`. You simply call `getCenter()` in a function that is called by a `mouseup` event, and then use those coordinates to immediately `setCenter()`?

```
function initMap(){

    ...

    var win = window;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(win, 'mouseup', setCoords);
    function setCoords(){
        var x = myMap.getCenter();
        var lat = x.lat();
        var lng = x.lng();
        myMap.addListener('center_changed', function(lat, lng){
        myMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
    };
};
```

The code above actually works, but the kicker is that it only works once until the browser becomes seemingly overloaded and produces the error **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**.

Not sure what to do now.

More info about this **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626454/functions-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-with-google-m)**.

Comment: The center_changed listener sets the map center, which fires a center_changed event, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for responding. Yeah, you're right. I realized that a little while ago. Funny thing is that you would expect it to work flawlessly without adding `myMap.addListener...` but it doesn't. It functions as if the code doesn't exist at all. Please check out my other thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626454/functions-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-with-google-m

Answer (score 0):

This one works just fine for me:

```
map.addListener("dragend", () => map.setCenter(map.getCenter()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem for my project by combining these two events:

1. [dragend](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.dragend)
2. [idle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.idle)

In situation with momentum *idle* works as expected, it is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming.

```
let dragFinished = false;

map.addListener("dragend", () => {
  dragFinished = true;
});

map.addListener("idle", () => {
  // idle could be fired after zooming also, but we need to catch it only after drag
  if (dragFinished) {
    dragFinished = false;
    const loc = map.getCenter()?.toJSON();
    if (!loc) {
      return;
    }
    // Call your handler here!
    onDragEnd(loc);
  }
});
```