# Google Maps On Bounds Changed Event When Fast Dragging and Release of Mouse

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the [Angular Google Maps](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/google-maps#readme) Javascript API and am trying to get event's for when the map moves (both translates and/or zooms). The issue is I get the event's while the user is interacting with the map and immediately after the user finishes interacting with the map, but there may or may not be a map animation that continues after the user finishes interacting with the map.

For example when you zoom in or out, you'd roll the scroll wheel maybe one or two click, but the map performs a "smooth animated" zoom. I'd like to get the change in map bounds **as the map is transitioning**. Currently I just get an event firing as the user's scroll wheel clicks.

As another example, when a user drags the map quickly and then releases the map while the map is still moving then the map will continue to move and "smoothly animate and slow down" to a stop. I'm not having issues getting boundsChanged events while the user is actively dragging, but when the user releases their mouse I get one more event fired and it has the **map bounds for where the map will be when the animation finishes**. I'd like to have the map bounds **as the animation is running**

I've looked at the `bounds_changed` and `center_changed` and `zoom_changed` [Map Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map-Events), but they don't seem to trigger while the animation is running.

Note: my question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019064/disable-drag-inertia-momentum-on-google-maps-v3), but different in that I don't want to disable the maps momentum/inertia, merely that I want to get correct bounds updates as the maps is moving due to momentum.

For background information, I have multiple other UI elements that surround my map that I want to keep in sync with the motion of the map.

Thanks for any help that is provided.

Comment: If the API doesn't behave the way you think it should behave, you can open a feature request in their issue tracker.